# Why can't I use "to the point that" here?

Tags: grammar, relative-clauses

> If you're anything like me, I'm sure you've found yourself, at one point or another, feeling trapped in this endless loop of work and play, week after week. And it gets to the point where all that matters is how we reward ourselves after a tough week at work.

I thought "to the point where" and "to the point that" are always interchangeable, but the lecturer said that you can't use 'that' because of the context. Is it true?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a very subtle point. Most native speakers, including myself, would use "that" in this context.

If I try and defend your lecturer's opinion, you could think of "the point" as a place. In that case, precise language would dictate that you use "where."

Overall I disagree with your lecturer, though. I don't know if they are *always* interchangeable, but "that" seems perfectly appropriate here, and in fact probably more natural.

Note that typical use patterns can be different in different countries. I'm not aware of this being one of those cases, but I could imagine that could be a cause of disagreement on this point, assuming your lecturer is a native speaker.

Comment: It's possible that the Lecturer thinks having '*that all that*' sounds clumsy ? I don't think it's incorrect though.